# Perl: what happens when we assign a constant value to a reference variable instead of address of a variable?

Tags: perl, reference

```
   Example:
    #! /usr/bin/perl -w

    $$var=10;
    print "Variable is containing $$var and is of type ". ref($$var)."\n";

    Output:
    $perl testRefVar.pl
    Variable is containing 10 and is of type
```

Here the variable $$var is not referring to any other variable, but a constant. So is there any significance of prefixing a variable with '$$'?

Comment: Perl's `${...}` is roughly C's `*`, and `\ ` corresponds to `&`. The expression `${$var} = 10` is equivalent to `*var = 10`. It's not `var = &10` or `var = 10`.

Answer (score 3):

This is the same as setting any other variable to 10, except that the access is indirect.

perl will *autovivify* an anonymous scalar variable and assign the reference to `$var` so that this action can be fulfilled. If you print out `$var` you will get something like `SCALAR(0x3ecec4)`.

To do this explcitily you could write

```
my $temp;
my $var = \$temp;
$$var = 10;
```

which would assign 10 to the variable `$temp`.

If, instead, you set `$var` to a reference to a *constant*, like this

```
my $var = \99;
$$var = 10;
```

you would get the error message

```
Modification of a read-only value attempted
```

because in this case `$var` refers to a *constant* instead of a *variable*.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes indeed it gives the following output on printing ref($var): Variable is containing 10 and is of type SCALAR

Answer (score 2):

Here, `$var` is a a reference to a scalar, and `$$var` is the scalar itself. Unless your code specifically wants references, the indirection (requiring the use of two dollar signs when you want the actual scalar) is at the very least a cumbersome hassle.